# I/O operation on closed file при повторной отправке .xlsx файла Телеграм ботом

Tags: python, telebot, openpyxl

Всем привет!

Пишу своего первого телеграм бота и столкнулся с такой ошибкой **I/O operation on closed file**, при повторной отпраке excel файла ботом пользователю.

Суть такая: пользователь нажимает на кнопки и пишет сколько и какой продукции он произвел, эти данные заносятся в отчет (отчет в формате .xlsx), после чего он жмет на кнопку "Рассчитать" и ему присылается готовый отчет с его введенными данными.
И вроде как всё даже работает, но только 1 раз!
При формировании нового отчета возникает **I/O operation on closed file**

Никак не могу победить эту ошибку

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

vpp = pd.read_excel(path_vpp_home, 'VPP')
vpp.rename(columns={'Код общий': 'code'}, inplace=True)

vpp_polish_ho_baltic = vpp.query("code == '4002.001.WC_BAL_HO'")['VPP'].to_numpy()
vpp_polish_ds = vpp.query("code == '4002.001.WC_DAS_ZZ'")['VPP'].to_numpy()

button_pol_baltic_ho = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Baltic HO", callback_data="polbalticho")
button_pol_ds_ho = types.InlineKeyboardButton("DS HO", callback_data="poldsho")
button_pol_total = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Рассчитать", callback_data="poltotal")

class Polish:
    def __init__(self, baltic_ho, ds_ho):
        self.baltic_ho = baltic_ho
        self.ds_ho = ds_ho

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_text(message):
    fc_pol_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    fc_pol_menu.add(button_pol_baltic_ho, button_pol_ds_ho)
    fc_pol_menu.add(button_pol_total)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери изделие:', reply_markup=fc_pol_menu)
    test = Polish(0,0)
    polish_path_home = 'C:\\Users\\alexn\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Python\\Telegram Bot\\polisher_master.xlsx'
    wb = load_workbook(polish_path_home)
    ws = wb['PolisherL1']

    def send_message_quant(call, calldata, send, funci):
        if call.data == calldata:
            send_mes = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, send)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(send_mes, funci)

    def baltic_ho(message):
        test.baltic_ho = message.text
        ws['G11'] = message.text
    def ds_ho(message):
        test.ds_ho = message.text
        ws['G20'] = message.text

    def check(call, model_p, mess):
        if int(model_p) > 0:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mess + str(model_p))

    def send_pol_total(call, calldata):
        if call.data == calldata:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Итого:')
            check(call, test.baltic_ho, 'Baltic ')
            check(call,test.ds_ho, 'DS HO ')
            activ = round((((float(test.baltic_ho) * float(vpp_polish_ho_baltic) +
            float(test.ds_ho) * float(vpp_polish_ds)) / 11.25)), 1)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Активность ' + str(activ))
            test.baltic_ho = 0
            test.ds_ho = 0
            save_polish_home = 'C:\\Users\\alexn\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Python\\Telegram Bot\\first.xlsx'
            wb.save(save_polish_home)
            f1 = open(save_polish_home, 'rb')
            bot.send_document(call.message.chat.id, f1)
            bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.id)
            wb.close()

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def callback_inline(call):
        if call.message:
            send_message_quant(call, "polbalticho", 'Количество Baltic', baltic_ho)
            send_message_quant(call, "poldsho", 'Количество DS HO', ds_ho)
            send_pol_total(call, "poltotal")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)



I/O operation on closed file.
  File "C:\Users\alexn\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\for_stack.py", line 66, in send_pol_total
    wb.save(save_polish_home)
  File "C:\Users\alexn\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\for_stack.py", line 77, in callback_inline
    send_pol_total(call, "poltotal")
  File "C:\Users\alexn\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\for_stack.py", line 79, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Вот полный код:

```
import telebot
import pandas as pd
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from telebot import types
from openpyxl import load_workbook, worksheet, cell
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from datetime import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# Загрузка VPP
path_vpp_work = 'C:\\Users\\nosale01\\Desktop\\Telegram-Bot\\vpp_data.xlsx'
path_vpp_home = 'C:\\Users\\alexn\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Python\\Telegram Bot\\vpp_data.xlsx'
vpp = pd.read_excel(path_vpp_work, 'VPP')

vpp.rename(columns={'Код общий': 'code'}, inplace=True)

vpp_polish_ho_baltic = vpp.query("code == '4002.001.WC_BAL_HO'")['VPP'].to_numpy()
vpp_polish_ds = vpp.query("code == '4002.001.WC_DAS_ZZ'")['VPP'].to_numpy()

button_pol_baltic_ho = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Baltic HO", callback_data="polbalticho")
button_pol_ds_ho = types.InlineKeyboardButton("DS HO", callback_data="poldsho")
button_pol_total = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Рассчитать", callback_data="poltotal")

class Polish:
    def __init__(self, baltic_ho, ds_ho):
        self.baltic_ho = baltic_ho
        self.ds_ho = ds_ho

test = Polish(0,0)
wb = load_workbook('C:\\Users\\nosale01\\Desktop\\Telegram-Bot\\polisher_master.xlsx')
ws = wb['PolisherL1']

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_text(message):
    fc_pol_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    fc_pol_menu.add(button_pol_baltic_ho, button_pol_ds_ho)
    fc_pol_menu.add(button_pol_total)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери изделие:', reply_markup=fc_pol_menu)

def send_message_quant(call, calldata, send, funci):
    if call.data == calldata:
        send_mes = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, send)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send_mes, funci)

def baltic_ho(message):
    test.baltic_ho = message.text
    ws['G11'] = message.text
def ds_ho(message):
    test.ds_ho = message.text
    ws['G20'] = message.text

def check(call, model_p, mess):
    if int(model_p) > 0:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mess + str(model_p))

def send_pol_total(call, calldata):
    if call.data == calldata:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Итого:')
        check(call, test.baltic_ho, 'Baltic ')
        check(call,test.ds_ho, 'DS HO ')
        activ = round((((float(test.baltic_ho) * float(vpp_polish_ho_baltic) +
        float(test.ds_ho) * float(vpp_polish_ds)) / 11.25)), 1)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Активность ' + str(activ))
        test.baltic_ho = 0
        test.ds_ho = 0
        now_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        save_polish_home = 'C:\\Users\\nosale01\\Desktop\\Telegram-Bot\\'+now_time+'.xlsx'
        wb.save(save_polish_home)
        f1 = open(save_polish_home, 'rb')
        bot.send_document(call.message.chat.id, f1)
        bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.id)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        send_message_quant(call, "polbalticho", 'Количество Baltic', baltic_ho)
        send_message_quant(call, "poldsho", 'Количество DS HO', ds_ho)
        send_pol_total(call, "poltotal")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: У вас wb создаётся при команде start потом вы закрываете wb.close() а дальше пытаетесь вызвать метод save у закрытого файла. О чем вам и говорит ошибка.

Comment: Логика создания документа какая?

Comment: Александр, да, wb  создаётся при команде start, а потом закрывается wb.close(), но потом, для нового ввода информации, я снова использую start т.е. снова создаю wb (возможно следует это сделать как-то по другому), но ошибка выползает именно при втором формировании отчета. 


Логика такая: Есть отформатированный отчет в .xlsx, в определенные ячейки подставляются значения введенные пользователем, потом документ сохраняется с новым именем и далее отправляется пользователю.

Comment: Если пользователь уже подписан на вашего бота то start не вызывается.

Comment: И вообще вы локальную переменную используете глобально? Покажите весь скрипт и исправьте форматирование а то у вас отступы не правильно расставлены.

Comment: По идее если вы планируете использовать файл повторно то зачем его закрывать, а если нет то открывайте файл перед тем как работать с ним.

Comment: Добавил полный код выше)

Comment: Пробовал делать не на команду старт, а на кнопку! Всё равно такая же ошибка. Отступы поправил - и снова ничего((

Comment: Убрал wb.close(), объявил wb и ws в самом начале.

Comment: Новое название отчета выбрал - это дата и время сейчас, в папке вижу, что файл создается и после второго вызова, но он не открывается с помощью excel, да и вес у него маленький!

Answer (score 0):

Победил наконец-то) Добавил функцию с объявлением глобальной wb и ws

```
def open_excel():
    global wb, ws
    wb = load_workbook(polish_path_home)
    ws = wb['PolisherL1']
    return wb, ws
```

Добавил сюда:

```
def send_pol_total(call, calldata):
    if call.data == calldata:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Итого:')
        check(call, test.baltic_ho, 'Baltic ')
        check(call,test.ds_ho, 'DS HO ')
        activ = round((((float(test.baltic_ho) * float(vpp_polish_ho_baltic) +
        float(test.ds_ho) * float(vpp_polish_ds)) / 11.25)), 1)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Активность ' + str(activ))
        test.baltic_ho = 0
        test.ds_ho = 0
        now_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        save_polish_home = 'C:\\Users\\nosale01\\Desktop\\Telegram-Bot\\'+now_time+'.xlsx'
        wb.save(save_polish_home)
        f1 = open(save_polish_home, 'rb')
        bot.send_document(call.message.chat.id, f1)
        bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.id)
        open_excel()
```